# How many heroes and villains are directly linked to the super serum originally

Tags: marvel, comics, captain-america

I previously believed that Bruce Banner was involved in trying to replicate the super-soldier serum that made Steve Rogers, his gamma ray experiments were trying to replicate that.

I also believe Man-Thing and Curtis Conners were also involved in research linked to the super serum, and their transformations came linked to that work.

How many and which Super Heroes' and Villains' from the comics, original storylines were linked to researching the Super Serum in some way, and how many (roughly) have had their original Origin Stories retconned to be linked to the Serum since? (I will ask a follow up question later based on this answer)

Just to clarify it is fairly easy to find the list of characters who have been given the super soldier serum. This question is not about them, it is about the characters who where created either as a side effect of trying to develop it, or in some other way had there origin linked to it.

Comment: Does it matter if the character gets retconned into being tied into the serum?  I think a significant number of characters in the comics who have been revealed to have a connection to the serum have had that connection added much later than their original origin story.

Comment: The Leader and The Abomination. Arguably, The Powerbroker became the villain they are as a direct consequence of the serum.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Indeed, Bruce Banner was originally researching gamma-rays.

Comment: In the [Ultimate Marvel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Marvel) universe, nearly every superhero/villain.

Comment: Question amended

Comment: The Red Skull also

Comment: So just comics Earth-616?

Comment: While not Marvel, the origin of the Creeper (Silver Age version) could qualify.

Comment: The Super Serum was not a very significant thing in Silver Age Marvel, probably because it wasn't something Stan Lee was involved in thinking up.  References to it only started cropping up frequently later on.

Comment: By "how many", do you mean that you're looking for a quantity? Or are you actually looking to identify which "heroes and villains are directly linked to the super serum originally"? If it's the latter, I think you should edit your question title accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Comic Book Resources](https://www.cbr.com/15-super-soldiers-besides-captain-america/), the following characters took some form of the SSS (Super-Soldier serum):

1. Captain America
2. Sentry - took an experimental version of the SSS
3. Red Skull - his mind was transferred (by [Zola](https://www.marvel.com/characters/arnim-zola)) in to a cloned body of Steve Rogers
4. Omega Red - given the KGB's version of the SSS
5. Luke Cage - agreed to experimental treatment, which was based on the Super-Soldier program
6. [Black Widow](https://www.marvel.com/characters/black-widow-natasha-romanoff) - given an experimental Super-Soldier treatment in the Red Room
7. [Isaiah Bradley](https://www.marvel.com/characters/isaiah-bradley) - underwent the Super-Soldier process before Rogers
8. [U.S.Agent](https://www.marvel.com/characters/us-agent-john-walker) - [Power Broker](https://www.marvel.com/characters/power-broker/in-comics) used a variant of the Super-Soldier process on him
9. Nuke
10. Warhawk
11. Mockingbird - In [New Avengers # 13](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/35261/new_avengers_2010_13), Fury gives Morse a combination of the SSS and the Infinity formula.
12. [Nomad](https://www.marvel.com/characters/nomad-jack-monroe) - Jack Munroe takes a version of the SSS to become the new Bucky
13. The Destroyer
14. [Master Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Man_(Marvel_Comics)) was subjected to the Nazi version of the SSS (I believe this was in [Giant-Size Invaders #1](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/51104/giant-size_invaders_1975_1))
15. Anti-Cap
16. [Man-Thing](https://www.marvel.com/characters/man-thing) - Ted Sallis attempts to recreate the SSS. In [Web of Spider-man (2009)](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/30641/web_of_spider-man_2009_6), it is revealed that Sallis at one point worked alongside [Curt Connors](https://www.marvel.com/characters/lizard-curtis-connors/in-comics).

[Eli Bradley](https://www.marvel.com/characters/patriot-elijah-bradley/in-comics) eventually receives a blood transfusion from his grandfather Isaiah, and gains similar powers.

In [Hulk No More](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/hulk-no-more/4045-56487/), M.O.D.O.K. works with General Ross to attempt to create gamma-powered super soldiers.

While [MVP](https://www.marvel.com/characters/mvp) has not taken any form of the SSS, he is the great-grandson of its inventor (Dr. Erskine).

Comment: Just to clarify this is not specifically characters who took it but those who where in and around trying to develop it. Curt Conners, from what I read on Man Things page, was involved in an attempt to recreate it and this led to him then discovering the technology to regrow his arm.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: ok that might have been me mis reading, I think Man Thing worked with Conners prior to working on the superserum, I mis read that to Conners working with him then but that is the kind of links I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In the 90's animated *Spider Man* (which has its own continuity), [Felicia Hardy](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Felicia_Hardy_(Earth-92131)) is given the serum. Apparently [her father](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/John_Hardesky_(Earth-92131)) knew the serum formula (quote is from the Felicia link)

> Felicia's father remained in S.H.I.E.L.D. custody until the Kingpin had the Chameleon infiltrate the Helicarrier he was in and switch places with him. After being captured by Doctor Octopus, Felicia was threatened to convince her father to hand over the formula to the Super-Soldier Serum. Felicia was also used to ensure the formula he gave was correct; Herbert Landon improved upon the formula; with an upgraded type of the same super-soldier project, Felicia was gifted with great physical powers.

Comment: This doesn't really cover the "how many" offer of the question, regardless of how interesting it is

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I think OP is not really asking "how many" but they're actually looking to identify which "heroes and villains are directly linked to the super serum originally."

Comment: @galacticninja he's but if someone said "how many continents?" Just replying "well, Africa's a continent" doesn't help as a complete answer when you want the full list

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I think the answerer didn't add more because a prior answer already has a list. This answer is an addendum to the prior list answer. List questions are likely to have answers such as this one.

Comment: @galacticninja ... I realise that. Addendums should be edits or comments, and list questions are only tolerated if the answers are complete. How do you accept an answer if there are two with partial lists?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage "*Addendums should be edits or comments*" That depends on the question (and the other answers). It is at the answerer's discretion if they want to edit an existing answer or comment or add another answer. As long as the answer is at least a partial one, it's fine to add another answer, especially on list questions. "*How do you accept an answer if there are two with partial lists?*" Accepting an answer is optional. If I had to accept, I'd accept the one with more correct items listed.  (Though that doesn't mean that the other answers, even partial ones, are not appreciated.)

Comment: To weigh in here, the inherent problem with a lot of these questions is they don't list what *continuity* they want. The other answer covers the 616 list. This one covers another continuity entirely (and said continuity is short). If that's still not acceptable I'll delete, but it did seem like a valid answer, and one that needed to be distinct from the other one.